# how to resolve this incompatible types found : java.lang.String required: java.lang.String[] return s;

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
public static String[] division2()
{
    String s=" ";
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]%3==0)
        {
            s+=fooff;           
        }
        if(a[i]%5==0)
        {
            s+=barrr;
        }
        if(a[i]%3==0 && a[i]%5==0)
        {
            s+=fooffbarrr;
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> ```
> incompatible types
> found   : java.lang.String
> required: java.lang.String[]return s;
> ```

Comment: Is *"types found : java.lang.String required: java.lang.String[]return s;"* really unclear? Return an array, instead of `s`.

Comment: Why don't you change return type to `String` from `String[]`. Also I would suggest you to change `s` to `StringBuilder` and return `s.toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options:

1) Change return type to String: public static String division2() {...}

2) Return String[] type: return s.split(""); - This method splits the string by the given string in the brackets and returns an array, for example:
"I@am@going@to@be@splitted".split("@"); returns array of 6 elements: "I", "am", 
"going", "to", "be", "splitted".